# Should this post not have been edited?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

To know what is considered an acceptable edit of (other's) answers and not, here on Stack Overflow: This can be frustration to users if we have different interpretations as we tend to feel ownership to our own posts - which is understandable. I would like to know what is acceptable in such a situation like this one.

A user gave [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30822237/1693593) which will work *per se*, but the user is missing a vital line (`beginPath`) which, if missing, will slow down the browser [significantly](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/hr99LcLn/) over time, as well as creating other problems when adding other paths, potentially making a visual mess.

I first posted a comment about this, then later when I saw no response I went ahead and added the line to the answer. I have gold badge in both tags [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) and [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) (currently the single holder) and I see weekly problems related to missing `beginPath()` in the code.

The user seems to have gotten offended by my edit, which of course was not the intention and posted this response in the comments:

> [..] also remember that's it's fine to correct minor issues on someone's
>   answer, but an answer is not a post: it's not fine to change their
>   code to do what you would have answered - that's what comments are for
>   and then the answerer can update their answer if necessary. (beginPath
>   is good advice, but in this case absolutely not necessary, which is
>   why I intentionally left it off, and edited the answer to take it out
>   again

Now, I do not just think it's necessary. I know it is for the reason mentioned above (and we're talking about a single line that will improve the code). The user indicates he knows about this as well, but despite of this chose to make an additional edit to *remove* the line making the answer less useful and correct.

I suspect this decision was more emotional-based than sensible, and I can understand the reason for that, but regardless, I think my decision to edit this was correct; the answerer feels probably the opposite.

[This section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) states:

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. > Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
>
>   to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
>
>   to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
>
>   to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a > single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

I considered this reason *"to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages"* not just in this instance, but also for future readers.

Being active in the canvas tags I see, as mentioned, weekly questions about correct usage of `beginPath()` (due to it being missing), so I know this can become an issue and won't be surprised to see a new post from this user in the future unless he observed the comment (or is already aware of this).

I also had the impression that Stack Overflow uses the wiki-principle; anyone can chip in on an edit, both answers and questions (assumed they know what they're doing).

But, I don't want to upset anyone, so I would like to know if I stepped over the line, or if my decision to make the edit was correct. What is acceptable?

**Update** for the record: The user has since updated the post using beginPath(), but since it is not about the user nor this answer in particular, but what is considered acceptable in a situation as this to avoid stepping on someone's toes, I would still like to know what the "consensus" is.

Comment: The other user is, strictly speaking, wrong about what an answer is. Answers *are* posts and *are* supposed to be edited to correct verifiable problems or make verifiable improvements. That's considered fairly crucial to building a database of Q&A that doesn't simply consist of innumerable comments correcting (or "correcting") various aspects of each post; actually editing at some point is generally necessary to make things readable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think anybody did anything fundamentally wrong in this whole story. Based on your description (I can't judge the technical merits of the edit), the whole process worked as it was supposed to:

- You left a comment first raising your concerns with the answer. IMHO, that's always the best first step.
- When you got no response to the comment, you made a small edit to the answer. I know that editing code is a touchy subject, but answers can be edited, and the code is part of the answer like everything else. Of course it should be done with care, but it sounds like you are qualified in the domain and applied your best judgment.
- The author of the answer did not like your edit, and rolled it back. They are perfectly within their rights to do that. After all, the answer has their name under it, and they can veto edits that they disagree with.

All in all, nothing bad happened here. There was a disagreement about an edit, and it was resolved. And yes, I do believe you should consider it resolved at this point. Once the OP rolled back your edit, it's time to step away. Fortunately, in this specific example, they ended up adopting a variation of your suggestion. But in the general case, it's time to stop after the rollback.

The only thing I might have done differently is to leave more time after your initial comment. I can't see the timeline with high precision. But when I checked, both your comment and your edit were shown as "4 hours ago". If that's the case, you must have pulled the trigger on the edit fairly quickly after adding the initial comment. It would have been better to give the poster more time to either edit the post themselves, or respond to your comment.

Comment: Tip: those fuzzy date strings like _"4 hours ago"_ have tooltips showing the exact date / time if you mouse-over on them.

Comment: @Cerbrus Cool, I had never noticed. Then again, I should have known that SO has tooltips on *everything*. ;)

Comment: I think had the user continued to reject your edit, I would have created a new answer with the change and posted a link to it in a comment on their answer.  Multiple, contradicting answers are common on SO...good ones float to the top over time.  Posters that accept good edits to their code will get rewarded with upvotes, those that don't face increased competition.