# What should I do about adding highly voted comment content to highly voted answer's content

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments

So I'm reviewing [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10108445), and I'm not exactly sure what is the line about adding a highly voted comment to an accepted and highly voted answer.

It does not clearly contradict author's content and doesn't really change the meaning of the question, in fact I'd say it improves it. Since comments are temporary things, I'd add it to the question, but op could have added it himself a long time ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally would not approve this edit. It may be good information, but it is still putting words into the original author's mouth. He/she may disagree with that comment for some technical reason, and it's not an editor's place to force the OP to include that information. For example, I think that kind of long ternary operator is a bit more difficult to read than the OP's proposed solution.

If you really think it's valuable, you can add it as your own answer and cite the comment. You can also make the answer a community wiki so you don't earn rep from someone else's contribution if you think that would make it more fair.

Comment: I would add that the original author is still an active member (hell, they were last seen an hour ago!) and has likely already seen that comment and just decided it wasn't worth it to add it to their answer.

Comment: _"putting words into the original author's mouth"_ - so? This is a community-curated site. If comments point out mistakes or inarguably useful additions, it is your obligation to include them in the post.

Comment: Related: [Should this post not have been edited?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296872/should-this-post-not-have-been-edited). As I'm not an subject-matter expert on this topic I can't say if this particular edit was harmful or not, but it's certainly not as black and white as _"You don't edit comments into answers"_. I hate it when there's a comment like _"Your code has this mistake"_ with fifty upvotes and nobody bothered to fix the answer and (flag to) remove the comment. Comments are meant to be temporary anyway.

Comment: @CodeCaster I disagree (with your first comment). I think it's the community's responsibility to help fix formatting, grammar, spelling, phrasing and word choice to make things as readable and understandable as possible, but I don't think the principle of community moderation and editing extends to modifying the core content of others' posts. That's one of the reasons we allow multiple answers. There are tools available to make sure the information readers need is visible without directly adding content to other people's posts.

Comment: @CodeCaster I do agree that it's obnoxious seeing comments that point out ways to improve answers that are never applied. But I would rather have that than people altering the content of other people's posts, just because they think they have a "better" way - which is exactly what happened here, as shown by the edit summary: " improved answer by adding the highly up voted comment to the answer, which is in fact the best answer in code to use to support IE". If the editor thinks that's the best way, then he/she should post their own answer instead of changing someone else's.

Comment: That's what I meant by not being an expert, I can't really address this specific issue. Just based on that phrasing, I'd have rejected the issue as well - such edit should not be made by <2K rep users. In general though, I do think that a subject-matter expert should be allowed to improve an answer if they can defend that edit.