# Typos in code snippet from a good answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, code, typographical-error

I tried to edit a typo in a code snippet in **answer** from another user ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693442/1503505), 4-letter edit to make, owner fixed it) but I couldn't even submit my change for review as it is only 5 char long.

This specific typo was quickly fixed but in a more general context, what is the right thing to do?

- Leave the typo and ask the owner to correct it in comments?
- Add some "junk" in edit to make it long enough:

  - add code comment?
  - add an "updated" line?
- Flag the answer?

According to [comment privilege help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) comments are not supposed to be used for correction:

> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;

Furthermore, what should be done if a typo persists after the owner was notified via comment?

- Nothing?
- Comment again?
- Downvote?

Comment: I'd opt for _"Leave the typo and ask the owner to correct it in comments?"_

Comment: *I tried to edit a typo in a code snippet* - never edit ANY part of the OP's code. You can always leave a comment.

Comment: well, there is an "edit" button... maybe this should be available at some higher privilege then

Comment: No. Edit button should not be used to edit typos or syntax errors

Comment: OK get it, edited my question to account for your comments. What should be done if a typo persists after a comment was left to owner?

Comment: This is not about the question but for an answer (a good one, accepted it juste after the typo was fixed); privilege section states this kind of minor edit should be OK: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296872/should-this-post-not-have-been-edited. The main problem is length limit, which prevents this edit (which could indeed be rejected).

Comment: @TheLostMind: for Preuk, "close" → "flag to close".

Comment: @Preuk - If it is an answer, you are free to DV it (if leaving a comment doesn't work).

Comment: Downvoting a correct, well-explained answer because of a typo sounds like a loss for community to me.

Comment: It's usually OK to fix obvious English mistakes in code when they are in comments or print statements (at least I think so).

Comment: Please, see related topic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits

Comment: Please, see related feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315974/code-block-edits-single-character-updates-to-compile-errors-new-feature-reque

Comment: Relevant answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/2751621. According to this (for code edits):
"Correct spelling/grammar issues in the answer body" is encouraged.

Comment: @TheLostMind nonsense; a total prohibition on code editing has *never* been a rule or community norm and goes against the advice at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/1709587

Comment: @MarkAmery  - Well.. Changing *technical details* in code is not acceptable and the link you pointed to implies the same thing. The only other things that could be changed are *code formatting* or other *non-technical* details.   *formatting code* is not *changing code*. Also, I don't think correcting typos is a good idea either. BTW people should be polite when they disagree with something someone says. *Nonsense..* is not the right way of talking to *anyone*.

Comment: @TheLostMind, actually the accepted [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/2751621) for that post encourages to "Fix syntax errors and typos*1". Note: there is a footnote that IMO is makes sense.

Comment: @TheLostMind about the polite thing. Doesn't that depend on the demographics? I mean, "nonsense" is a polite word here. Bullshit on the other hand... .

Comment: @ElvioMartinelli - yes it says "fix syntax errors and typos" but only for **answers**. Code in **questions** should be left alone as the apparent errors could well be the source of the problem.

Comment: @ChrisF - I fully agree with you, but this discussion is about answers, isn't?

Comment: @ElvioMartinelli - true, but you have to be careful as people can (and do) interpret it as it being OK to edit code in questions.

Comment: i'll put emphasis on "answer" to avoid confusion then

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Well let's quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60763/213575):

> If the error appears to be an *inadvertent* mistake or omission, **then fix it if you can.**
>
> If it appears that the author *intended* to write what he wrote, then leave it be. Down-vote it. Maybe leave a comment. But don't correct it - if it turns out that he was right, you'll have just sabotaged his efforts, and even if he is truly wrong, he may be fond of his ignorance, and his example may prove instructive to others who hold similar notions.

So, yeah, you have the tools, the time and the knowledge to fix it; go ahead and fix it! BTW, your edit could have been accepted by the system if you had thrown in some indentation.

Comment: Tried re-indenting it to raise char count to no avail.

Comment: _"your edit could have been accepted by the system if you throw in some indentation."_ Whitespace for indenting/formatting code doesn't count for the 6 character limit for suggested edits. cc @Preuk (whitespace in general doesn't, really.)

Comment: @Kendra: so when < 2k rep and fix is small, what can be done?

Comment: @Preuk Either find something fluff to fix (Like a small re-wording that keeps intent (which _might_ not get past the queue)) or just comment on the post, unfortunately. (Unless you scour the post and manage to find a grammar fix or a spelling typo! Then just fix those.) It can be a pain, but at least you and I have enough rep to comment on the issue. It'd be a bigger pain if we didn't.